# Why is the breakpoint showing the second value of my array to be a large number? Extra Credit work

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Using nested `while` loops to count the number of each character in a given string and put those numbers in an array. Then finding the largest number in the array to determine the most common character. Returning this character to the caller.

When placing a breakpoint |down (noted below) Im getting the first array value to be correct, and the second to be incorrect.
I don't know where I'm going wrong. I do have to admit I'm quite burned out right now, so it could be something easy I'm overlooking. I don't know.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

char median(char *);
int main() {
    const int SIZE = 50;
    char thing[SIZE];
    char *strPtr;

    cout << " give me a string: " << endl;
    cin.getline(thing, SIZE);
    strPtr = thing;
    char mostcommon = median(strPtr);
    cout << mostcommon;
}

char median(char *strPtr) {
    char holder = 'x';
    int numberof[50];
    int counter = 0;
    int arrayspacecounter = 0;
    int thirdcounter;
    int fourthcounter;
    while (*strPtr != '\0') {
        holder = *strPtr;
        while (*strPtr != '\0') {
            strPtr++;
            if (holder == *strPtr) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        numberof[arrayspacecounter] = counter; //counts the number of each character. 
        arrayspacecounter++;
        strPtr++;
        counter = 0;
    }
```

v
// break point set HERE
^

```
    //find the largest number in numberof[]
    int largest = 0;
    for (thirdcounter = 0; thirdcounter <= 100; thirdcounter++) {
        for (fourthcounter = 1; fourthcounter <= 100; fourthcounter++) {
            if (largest < numberof[fourthcounter]) {
                largest = numberof[fourthcounter];
            }
        }
    }
    return *(strPtr + (largest));
}
```

Comment: Quick note you could use the ascii value of the char to do this too

Comment: I might be a bit burned out myself but it seems to me like you might be going about this the longer way. If all you're doing is counting the frequency of each character, you could use their ascii value as index in an array of 26 characters (say you capitalize all the letters). and keep a max as you insert the values in the frequency table.

Answer (score 1):

`numberof` is not initialised so will initially contain junk values, any unused entries will still contain junk values where your breakpoint is. Use:

```
int numberof[50] = { 0 };
```

Next `fourthcounter` goes up to 100 but you only have 50 elements in `numberof`, replace the magic number `50` with a constant like `MAX_ELEMENTS`:

```
const size_t MAX_ELEMENTS = 50;
int numberof[MAX_ELEMENTS] = { 0 };
....
for (thirdcounter = 0; thirdcounter < MAX_ELEMENTS; thirdcounter++)
{
    for (fourthcounter = 1; fourthcounter < MAX_ELEMENTS; fourthcounter++)
    {
```

Alternatively just use the `arrayspacecounter` you have created already:

```
for (thirdcounter = 0; thirdcounter < arrayspacecounter; thirdcounter++)
{
    for (fourthcounter = 1; fourthcounter < arrayspacecounter; fourthcounter++)
    {
```

I'm not sure why you have two for loops at the end? The outer one seems redundant. Fixing various other bugs results in the working function:

```
char median(const char* strPtr)
{
    const size_t MAX_ELEMENTS = 50;
    int numberof[MAX_ELEMENTS] = { 0 };

    int counter = 0;
    int arrayspacecounter = 0;
    int fourthcounter;
    const char* temp = strPtr;
    while (*temp != '\0')
    {
        const char* holder = temp;
        while (*temp != '\0')
        {
            temp++;
            if (*holder == *temp)
            {
                counter++;
            }

        }
        numberof[arrayspacecounter] = counter; //counts the number of each character. 
        arrayspacecounter++;
        temp = holder;
        temp++;
        counter = 0;

    }
    //find the largest number in numberof[]
    int largest = 0;
    for (fourthcounter = 1; fourthcounter < arrayspacecounter; fourthcounter++)
    {
        if (numberof[largest] < numberof[fourthcounter])
        {
            largest = fourthcounter;
        }
    }
    return *(strPtr + (largest));
}
```

Your code could be much simpler though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

char median(const char*);
int main()
{
    char mostcommon = median("test");
    std::cout << mostcommon;
}

char median(const char* strPtr)
{
    std::map<char, int> frequencies;
    for (auto ch = strPtr; *ch != '\0'; ch++)
    {
        frequencies[*ch]++;
    }
    auto max = std::max_element(frequencies.begin(), frequencies.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.second < b.second; });
    return max->first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program segfaults in median somewhere, my guess is that you're trying to use a position outside of the boundaries of your array somewhere.

If all you're wanting to count frequency try something simpler, like this for example.

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
   std::string phrase;
   std::cout << "Enter a phrase \n";
   std::getline(std::cin,phrase);
   int a = 'A'; //index 0 of your array
   int count=0;int max=0;
   int counter[26] = {0}; //array that will hold your frequencies
   char highestFreq;
   for(char c:phrase) {
      if(!isspace(c)) count = ++counter[int(toupper(c))-a];
      if(count>max) max=count, highestFreq=c;
   }
   std::cout << "max is: "<<max << ". The letter is '"<< highestFreq << "'.\n"<< std::endl;
}
```